# Control + Z (undo) not working in Query Tool -- Postgres

Tags: pgadmin-4

I am new in Postgres.

I am using the query tool to make some exercises for college and I can not undo lines written as in any code editor with control+z. I don´t know why this is happening as other shortcuts like control+c or control+v are working.

Hope anybody can help me as writing code without being able to undo is a nightmare

Comment: I assume with "Query Tool" you mean the query tool in pgAdmin. I added the relevant tag. If you are using a different SQL client, please change the tag accordingly

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that. The "Query Tool" in pgAdmin. Thanks for the clarification